# Problems when using Arduino EthernetUdp library

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to use the Arduino EthernetUdp library but I'm getting this error which I do not quite understand.

```
GenericEthernetSoftware.ino: In function 'void udpSend()':
GenericEthernetSoftware:217: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
```

Here is the code not compiling

```c
void udpSend(){
  if(millis() > lastPost + 10000){
    EthernetUDP.beginPacket(ip, 2026); //(line 217)
    EthernetUDP.write("{");
    EthernetUDP.write("\"Id\":\"5\"");
    EthernetUDP.wrte("\"A1\":\"5\"");
    EthernetUDP.write("\"A2\":\"5\"");
    EthernetUDP.write("\"A3\":\"5\"");
    EthernetUDP.write("}");
    EthernetUDP.endPacket();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the function `void PostOverUdp()`?  That's where the error seems to be

Comment: @jdotjdot, sorry, i renamed the method but not the error code. I've corrected my code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. They changed the library so I now have to use an instance of the EhternetUdp class. It's now compiling and working.

```c
EthernetUDP Udp;

void UdpSetup(){
  //Setup
}

void udpSend(){
  if(millis() > lastPost + 10000){
    Udp.beginPacket(ip, 2026);
    Udp.write("{");
    Udp.write("\"Id\":\"5\"");
    Udp.write("\"A1\":\"5\"");
    Udp.write("\"A2\":\"5\"");
    Udp.write("\"A3\":\"5\"");
    Udp.write("}");
    Udp.endPacket();
  }
}
```